# SQL: How to extract one row by MAX in another column and DISTINCT in yet another sequence of columns?

Tags: sql

Say I have a table with columns A, B, C, and D.
What I want is to

- get all the distinct combinations of A and B that there exists in the original table.
- for every such combination, I want extract a SINGLE row that has that combination, plus I also want its C and D value.
- there will probably be multiple rows that have that particular combination of A and B. In that case, I still only want just one row, and it should be the one with the highest value in the C column.

For example, if in my original table I have A = Male or Female, B = Tall or Short, and C = Age, and D is something else, then I want to end up with a table with 4 rows, each having one of these combinations:

```
Male, Tall, …, …
Female Tall, …, ...
Male Short, …, ...
Female Short, …, …
```

where each row should belong to the person with the biggest age, and then their respective D value as well.

Comment: why don't you provide some sample data and your desired output in table format rather all this textual explanation! That's easier to understand

Answer (score 2):

Gordon's answer is wrong. Use this:

```
select a, b, c, d
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b order by c) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Your answer only varies from [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64433050/3025856) by one character—ordering by `c` instead of `a`. If that is, in fact, necessary, that would be better suited as a suggested edit to Gordon's answer (which you can do now) or as a comment on his answer (which you'll need 50 reputation to do).

Comment: FYI: Gordon has since updated his answer to account for selecting the "highest value in the C column", as specified by the OP. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to group by columns A and B, and get max,sum,avg or any other function value of columns C and D a simple group by clause might work, example;

```
select a, b, max(c), max(d)
from table
group by a,b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select a, b, c, d
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b order by c desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Another contributor, @mikail, reports that this should be `order by c`. They don't have the reputation to comment, so they instead left the proposed correction as a new answer. I wanted to let you know so you could assess that recommendation and correct your code if it's a typo—or reply back to mikail if your `order by` clause is, in fact, correct. (Since the OP wants the highest value by `c`, I _believe_ mikail is correct?)

Comment: @JeremyCaney . . . I see that condition now in the question.